# Зачем нужен ALLOWED_HOSTS в Django?

Tags: django

В Django в файле settings немаловажным считается список ALLOWED_HOSTS, который, как я понял, определяет, на каких адресах Django в принципе может работать и отзываться на запросы. Однако я не понял, зачем это нужно, ибо при runserver мы итак устанавливаем адрес, на котором Django слушает. Так зачем отдельно это вписывать ещё и в ALLOWED_HOSTS?

Comment: Не адреса, а хосты. На одном адресе может быть любое (в том числе бесконечное) количество хостов

Comment: Че то не понял. Как это на одном адресе много хостов? Можешь привести пример ситуации, где это применяется?

Comment: Хост — это просто набор буковок в [HTTP-заголовке Host](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host), и туда может написать кто угодно что угодно

Comment: То есть allowed hosts это список, при наличии элементов которого в заголовке host джанго будет реагировать успешно, я так понял?